# Best way to backtest trading bots in pandas, for large DataFrames, without testing the strategy row by row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

What is the fastest way to turn

```
df[["Strat1", "Close"]]

    Strat1  Close
0   Sell    14185.250000
1   Sell    14185.150391
2   Sell    14157.320312
3   Sell    14184.709961
4   Sell    14185.139648
5   Buy     14171.000000
6   Buy     14166.919922
7   Buy     14150.009766
8   Buy     14136.209961
9   Sell    14131.889648
10  Sell    14129.969727
11  Buy     14135.500000
12  Buy     14135.500000
13  Buy     14135.500000
14  Sell    14135.500000
15  Buy     14135.500000
```

Into

```
df[["Strat1", "Close"]]

    Strat1  Close
0   Sell    14185.250000
1           14185.150391
2           14157.320312
3           14184.709961
4           14185.139648
5   Buy     14171.000000
6           14166.919922
7           14150.009766
8           14136.209961
9   Sell    14131.889648
10          14129.969727
11  Buy     14135.500000
12          14135.500000
13          14135.500000
14  Sell    14135.500000
15  Buy     14135.500000
```

Do you have to iterate through the DataFrame line by line? My dataframe has 1.4 million rows of data so iterating line by line will inevitably take a while, also I have lots of columns "Strat2", "Strat3" that I want to test, further increasing the length of time taken to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you only need the first buy/sell entry, you can do:

```
df[df.Strat1 != df.Strat1.shift()]

# if you need the in between value to calculate pnl
df['signal'] = df.Strat1[df.Strat1 != df.Strat1.shift()].reindex(df.index)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
df["Strat1"] = (
    df["Strat1"]
    .groupby((df["Strat1"] != df["Strat1"].shift()).cumsum())
    .transform(lambda x: [x.iat[0], *[""] * (len(x) - 1)])
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Strat1         Close
0    Sell  14185.250000
1          14185.150391
2          14157.320312
3          14184.709961
4          14185.139648
5     Buy  14171.000000
6          14166.919922
7          14150.009766
8          14136.209961
9    Sell  14131.889648
10         14129.969727
11    Buy  14135.500000
12         14135.500000
13         14135.500000
14   Sell  14135.500000
15    Buy  14135.500000
```